# SSRS Report Viewer + SQL Server 2008R2 + "x-content-type-options" value="nosniff" The report does not render

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportviewer, owasp

I am using Report viewer 10.0.0.0 
Database instance and Report server is 2008R2 (10.50.6000)

For security reasons we have added a custom header "x-content-type-options", "nosniff" on the web.config

Which in turn when the report is ready to render, nothing is render.
If I remove the custom header, then the report is rendered

Any idea on how to leave the custom header on and the report viewer to work ?
Thanks